# How to remove the line 'Prepared for submission to JCAP'?

Tags: pdftex

I am using the JCAP latex package ([jcappub.sty](https://jcap.sissa.it/jcap/help/JCAP_TeXclass.jsp)) for writing latex documents. But I always get a line on the first page of the document - ''Prepared for submission to JCAP'. How to remove this line?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Welcome! Just add

```
\makeatletter
\gdef\@fpheader{}
\makeatother
```

before

```
\begin{document}
```

Example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{jcappub}
\title{An example title where \boldmath $x=1$}
\author[a]{First Author,} 
\author[a,b,1]{Second Author% 
\note{On leave from XXX.}} 
\author[a,c]{and Third Author}
\affiliation[a]{Institution,\\
 Street number, City, Country}
\affiliation[b]{Department, University,\\
 Street number, City, Country}
\affiliation[c]{Another University,\\
Street number, City, Country}
\emailAdd{author@inst.edu} 
\emailAdd{buthor@univ.country} 
\emailAdd{cuthor@another.univ.country}
\abstract{Text, text $math$, $math$ text, text. Text, text $math$, $math$ text,
text... }
\keywords{keyword one, keyword two} 
\arxivnumber{1234.5678}
\makeatletter
\gdef\@fpheader{}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\section{Introduction}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Indeed useful for removing any header from journal packages like JHEP.